# Calculate percentage of time disk is reading/writing using python

Tags: python, monitoring, disk, psutil

I am trying to set up some system monitoring.  I want to calculate the percentage of time the disk is processing read or write requests.  I am try to do this with [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil).  My current solution looks like this:

```
readtime = (psutil.disk_io_counters().read_time / 1000) / 1000
writetime = (psutil.disk_io_counters().write_time / 1000) / 1000
busytime = readtime + writetime;

percentage = (busytime) / 60
print(percentage)
```

The double divide by 1000 is because I read somewhere that `read_time` returns nano seconds.  My issue is this solution only ever return 4% even when I run a disk defragmentation and disk % is at 100 it returns 4%.  I must be misunderstanding what `read_time` and `write_time` are used for.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or have an alternative solution?  I am currently testing this on Windows 10 environment.

Comment: not sure if this is related, but i think the [psutil docs](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.disk_io_counters) state `read_time` is in *milliseconds* not nano seconds

Comment: @downshift I thought so too but the numbers it was returning were too big.  I found an [post](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/700) that said it was actually nano seconds, which looked more correct.  I maybe wrong though.